# How to apply existing CSS class to a generated HTML id/class from CSS file

Tags: html, css

I want to keep all my style in CSS file. I don't want to rewrite existing CSS, I want to reuse existing classes.

I have a standard CSS classes, like:

```
.greenArea{
    background-color:#4CAF50;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

I generate some buttons, that I want to apply this class to, but I don't want to do it from JS, I want to do it in CSS, so all styles would be in one place.

```
let btn = document.createElement("button")
btn.name = "start_btn"
```

**Is there CSS syntax to apply CSS class to some HTML object?**

Like this (*fictional code structure*):

```
button[name="start_btn"]{
  apply-class: greenArea;
}
```

Comment: _“Is there CSS syntax to apply CSS class to some HTML object?”_ - no, there is not. CSS’ purpose is to format elements, but not change their attributes.

Comment: But is there a way to reference one class from another?

Comment: No, not in CSS. In LESS/SASS there are ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that in CSS because CSS doesn't change elements attributes, but alternatively, you can use `hover,active,focus`..... to detect elements case and apply some codes to the cases.
[CSS cases link](https://bitsofco.de/when-do-the-hover-focus-and-active-pseudo-classes-apply/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with SASS placeholder Selector. In documentation they explained [well](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors).

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/SelenGora/pen/xxKVoXZ)

```
// Html
<button name="start_btn">I created dynamicly</button>
<button name="start_btn">I created dynamicly too</button>
<button name="yellow_btn">Whoa I'm yellow</button>


// Scss
%greenArea {
    background-color:#4CAF50;
    color:#ffffff;
}

%yellowArea {
    background-color:yellow;
    color:#000;
}

button[name="start_btn"]{
    @extend %greenArea;
}

button[name="yellow_btn"]{
    @extend %yellowArea;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can instead handle it like:

```
let btn = document.createElement("button")
btn.name = "start_btn"
btn.className = "greenArea";
```

This will create element as:

```
<button name="start_btn" class="greenArea"></button>
```

Comment: As stated in questions, JS is not an option

Comment: then probably you can use SCSS/SASS `extend`(ref: https://sass-lang.com/guide)

Example:
`%message-shared {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
}

.message {
  @extend %message-shared;
}`